# Do these syntactically correct C++ statements carry any meaning?

Tags: c++, syntax

When looking through the C++ grammar I discovered that postfixes are defined roughly like this:

```
Postfix ::=  Primary
        |    Postfix '['  Expression ']'
        |    Postfix '('  Expression ')'
        |    Postfix '.'  Identifier
        |    Postfix '->' Identifier
        |    Postfix '++'
        |    Postfix '--'
```

Meaning that `foo.f++()` would be syntactically valid--presumably because functions are pointers it would refer to the next function that was defined, but I would be shocked if it wasn't caught during the semantic parse as modifying a const object--as would `foo.f()<true>;` which doesn't seem to have any meaning at all, while `foo.++f()` wouldn't be allowed, even though it does more or less the same thing as the first one. Furthermore, unary expressions are defined so that `++*"hello world"` would be syntactically valid because literals are considered the same way that identifiers are.

Conversely something like:

```
postfix0 ::= ScopeResolution
         |   postfix0 '.' postfix2
         |   postfix0 '->' postfix2

postfix1 ::= postfix0
         |   postfix1 '<' expression '>'

postfix2 ::= postfix1
         |   postfix2 '[' expression ']'
         |   postfix2 '(' expression ']'

postfix3 ::= postfix2
         |   Literal
         |   postfix3 '++'
         |   postfix3 '--'
```

Would appear catch such invalid expressions during the syntactic phase of the parse.  At first I thought that it was just left in the standard as a legacy thing, but newer languages such as Java and D do the same thing, so is there some sort of meaning that those statements carry that leads to the grammar being defined that way?

Comment: `foo.f++` is parsed as `(foo.f)++`. `foo.++f` can't be parsed. What would it be, `(foo.++)f`?

Comment: The grammar doesn't know about the type system, and trying to make the grammar catch things the type system prohibits would make parsing even harder than it already is. Maybe `foo` has a function pointer member named `f`, and `foo.f++()` calls `foo.f()` and postincrements `foo.f`. It's much easier to determine whether it's valid outside the grammar.

Comment: `.` must be immediately followed by an identifier, which makes `foo.++f()` a syntax error.

Comment: There are things that can be parsed but are still invalid, e.g. `1 = 1;`

Comment: @user2357112: You probably meant a functor, not a function pointer, since functor objects might have `operator++` defined, but function pointers can't.

Comment: @BenVoigt: `++` for function pointers is just pointer arithmetic, isn't it?

Comment: @user2357112: It would be, if there were such a thing.  "The operand of prefix ++ is modiﬁed by adding 1, or set to true if it is bool (this use is deprecated). The operand shall be a modifiable lvalue. **The type of the operand shall be an arithmetic type or a pointer to a completely-defined object type**." and "For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic or unscoped enumeration type, or one operand shall be **a pointer to a completely-defined object type** and the other shall have integral or unscoped enumeration type."  No arithmetic on function pointers or pointer-to-members.

Comment: and for completeness sake, "The  value  of  a  postfix  ++  expression  is  the  value  of  its  operand.   [ Note:  the  value  obtained  is  a  copy  of
the original value  — end note ] The operand shall be a modifiable lvalue.  **The type of the operand shall be an arithmetic type or a pointer to a complete object type**.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Huh. You're right; I got function pointers and pointers *to* function pointers mixed up. There's no way to control the allocation of functions and no way to tell where `f++` would point even if you could force functions to go next to each other, so arithmetic on function pointers isn't meaningful.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, are you sure `1 = 1` is syntactically valid? I don't know about C++, but in most languages lvalues are syntactically determined, and `1` doesn't look the least bit likely to be one.

Answer (score 10):

C++ isn't actually defined by its grammar productions.  The BNF grammar is provided as an accompaniment to the rules of the language to aid in understanding, but there is not, and cannot be, a distinction between *syntax errors* and *semantic errors* in C++, because it does not have a context-free grammar.

So the improvement you're trying to make in changing "syntactically valid... caught during the semantic parse" to "catch such invalid expressions during the syntactic phase of the parse" is completely meaningless, since these don't actually exist as independent phases.

The phases of C++ compilation are found in section 2.1, `[lex.phases]` of the Standard.  Of particular interest to this topic is phase 7:

> White-space characters separating tokens are no longer significant.  Each preprocessing token is converted into a token. (2.7).  The resulting tokens are syntactically and semantically analyzed and translated as a translation unit.

Syntactic and semantic analysis are performed together, inseparably.  Semantic errors *are* caught during the syntactic phase of the parse, phase 7.

Answer (score 5):

As another fun note, `foo.f++()` can be semantically valid.  But it has nothing at all to do with "the next function defined".

```
#include <iostream>

struct CallMe {
    void operator()() const
    { std::cout << "Used as function call.\n"; }
};

struct F_Type {
    CallMe operator++(int)
    { std::cout << "f was incremented.\n"; return {}; }
};

struct Foo_Type {
    F_Type f;
} foo;

int main()
{
    foo.f++();
}
```

Output:

```
f was incremented.
Used as function call.
```

Comment: Works, but would be much more realistic for `operator++` to return its own type, and have `operator()()` in `F_Type`.

Comment: Awesome answer; “_parses_ fine but isn't usually supported _semantically_ by the types in question” is entirely reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

Just tried to compile and run this little program with `gcc` and `g++`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo() {
    printf("foo()\n");
}

int main(void) {
    void (*bar)() = foo;
    bar++();
    bar();
}
```

If interpreted as C code, there is no compiler error, the string "foo()\n" is printed two times, but it segfaults when it tries to return from `foo()` because part of the function prolog seems to have been skipped.

So, yes, at least `gcc` thinks that `bar++()` is valid C code, and expediently does nonsense.

**Update:**
As zwol points out (thank for that), this is due to a rather dangerous than useful gnu extension, which treats pointers to `void` and functions as pointers to objects of size 1, allowing pointer arithmetic on them. Compiling with `gcc --pedantic -Werror` yields the expected error, `gcc -std=c99` doesn't.

---

Different story with `g++`: Here I get the compiler error

```
foo.c: In function ‘int main()’:
foo.c:9:5: error: ISO C++ forbids incrementing a pointer of type ‘void (*)()’ [-fpermissive]
```

This is a provision within the C++ standard (section 5.2.6, as pointed out by Ben Voigt, thanks): pointer arithmetic on function pointers is not defined in C++.

Comment: Did you happen to read the comments on the question, where "some provision" is spelled out?

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah, thanks. Updated my answer to include that information.

Comment: It's section 5.2.6 in the Standard if you decide to put that quote in your answer.  (You should, comments get mass-deleted at times)

Comment: The effect in C is due to [one of GCC's least useful extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.1.0/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html). In the absence of this extension, `bar++` violates a constraint in C99 6.5.6p2 (pointer operands to + and - shall be pointers to *object* types), having been referred there from 6.5.2.4p2,3 (defining ++ and -- in terms of += and -=).

Comment: @zwol Thanks, didn't know that. I added a paragraph on that to the answer, hope you like it :-)

Comment: I'm not a fan of describing software design decisions as "braindead" - it's a _very_ strong term for something that presumably made sense at the time (which was 25 or more years ago), even if neither I nor anyone I've ever talked to has any idea what the rationale for this particular extension is...

Comment: @zwol Ok, softened my words a bit :-)

Comment: This extension is actually quite useful; you just haven't seen the context where it is useful. `void*` is the type of a memory buffer, and pointer arithmetic on memory buffers to get the size or to select portions of them makes a lot of sense.